# Is there an age restriction for a Polish student visa?

Tags: working-visas, student-visa, poland

I am currently working for a finance company with 14 years in data analytics. Now, I see a hard stop to my career and I am interested in an AI/ML course, especially in Poland.
Is there an age restriction as such to obtaining a student visa for Poland?